# Infinite-dimensional "algebraic varieties"

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, hilbert-spaces

This question was also formerly posted on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4338314/infinite-dimensional-algebraic-objects) but has not received any answer or comment.

Let $H$ be the infinite-dimensional seperable complex Hilbert space, and $P(H)$ denote its projectivization. It can be seen that $P(H)$ is a complex Hilbert manifold (modelled on $H$) and has homotopy type $K(\Bbb{Z},2)$.
Suppose $A$ is a continuous symmetric $d$-linear functional on $H$. Define the homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$ w.r.t. $A$ as $p_A : H \rightarrow \Bbb{C} : v \mapsto A(\underbrace{v,v,...,v}_{d \text{ times}})$. Each $p_A$ has a well-defined zero locus in $P(H)$ due to the homogenity. Call $p_A$ non-singular if its Fréchet derivative (which, at a given point, is a continuous linear functional on $H$ and can be canonically identified with an element in $H$) is non-zero everywhere aside from the origin. In this case, the zero locus of $p_A$ is also a complex Hilbert manifold and can be safely called a **variety**.

**Question**: Is the transverse intersection of finitely many (can be $1$) varieties always non-generic, e.g. they have finitely generated total homotopy groups (like the varieties of degree $1$ which have the same homotopy type $K(\Bbb{Z},2)$), infinite automorphism groups, etc.? In particular, since the unit sphere in $H$ is diffeomorphic to $H$ itself which admits a complex structure, is it also realizable as a transverse intersection of finitely many varieties? (*probably has a negative answer if my attempt below is valid*)

**Attempt**: Assuming a modified infinite-dimensional version of Lefschetz hyperplane theorem (**LHT**) yields a rather surprising answer: Choose a countable complete orthonormal basis of $H$ (denoting it $\{ e_i \}_{i=0}^{\infty}$). Let $x_i$ be the inner product with $e_i$, then $[x_i]:=[x_0 : x_1 : \cdots]$ is a homogeneous coordinate system on $P(H)$. Consider the degree-$d$ Veronese map $$V_d: P(H) \rightarrow P(H): [x_i] \mapsto \left[ \sqrt{\frac{d!}{l_{1}! \cdots l_{d}!}} x_{k_1}^{l_1} \cdots x_{k_d}^{l_d} \right]$$ where $0 \le l_1 \le \cdots \le l_d \le d$ is an integer partition of $d$ and the coordinates of the image are arranged so that $l_1 k_1 + \cdots + l_d k_d$ is increasing. The map is well-defined since $\lVert V_d(x) \rVert = \lVert x \rVert^d$ is finite. Because $V_d$ is a holomorphic injection, $S_d:=\mathrm{Im} (V_d)$ is a complex (*closed?*) submanifold of $P(H)$ isomorphic to $P(H)$ itself, being both infinite-dimensional and co-infinite-dimensional. A large number of degree-$d$ varieties <s>(*to be precise, the varieties correspond to [completely continuous](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Completely-continuous_operator) polynomials*)</s> are mapped to closed hyperplane sections of $S_d$, and formally apply **LHT** to them leads to the result that all codimension-$1$ varieties are homotopically indistinguishable regardless of the degree. Moreover, since the varieties are Hilbert manifolds, a homotopy equivalence will imply a diffeomorphism (see [this Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_manifold#Properties)). This sounds ridiculous, but things related to infinity are sometimes ridiculous, so I'm willing to know whether my attempt can be actually transformed into a strict proof.

**Motivation**: Low-degree (compared to the dimension of the ambient space) complex hypersurfaces and their intersections have simpler topology and richer symmetries in contrast to the high-degree generic ones. I'm wondering if every finite number is "low enough" compared to the infinity of the dimension of a Hilbert space.

**Related question**: Since the continuity of $p_A$ influences the formal application of **LHT**, what will happen if the projectivization at the start is performed on $H$ with weak topology? It does not seem to change the homotopy type of $P(H)$, but the varieties are no longer Hilbert manifolds.

Comment: How is transverse intersection defined in the infinite-dimensional case?

Comment: @LSpice In my differential topology class, $2$ sub-manifolds are said to intersect transversely if their tangent spaces $T_1,T_2$ (seen as a subspace of the tangent space $T$ of ambient manifold) at their intersection point span the whole $T$. And the transversity of multiple sub-manifolds is the transversity of the $(k+1)$-th sub-manifold and the intersect manifold of the first $k$ sub-manifolds for each $k$. I think this definition is suitable for the infinite-dimensional case if we only consider finite intersection.

Comment: There might be problems with the "weakly sequential continuous" thing. The reason I add this is that the "moduli space" of degree-$d$ varieties in $P(H)$ may vastly differ from $P(H)$ due to the difference of strong and weak convergence.

Comment: It seems to me that such a Hilbert variety contains a dense ind-variety which is homotopy equivalent to the ambient variety. And you can directly apply Lefschetz to the finite dimensional varieties making up the ind-variety. Thus such a regular complete intersection is homotopy equivalent to $K(\mathbb Z,2)$. In particular, consider the representative of an element of a homotopy group $f: S^n\to X$. For a big enough finite dimensional vector space $V\subset H$, the image of $f$ is close to $PV$. Then a geodesic homotopy gets it actually into $PV$ and apply Lefschetz to $PV\cap X$.

Comment: I think I equivocated between two ind-varieties. The canonical one uses all finite-dimensional subspaces of $H$. The map from its $\mathbb C$-points to that of the Hilbert variety should be a continuous bijection, but not a homeomorphism. Canonical choices allow slick proofs, but I suspect that there are thorny details in the uncountable colimit. Instead, fix a filtration by finite-dimensional subspaces with dense union. Then the countable union topology is the subspace topology from the Hilbert manifold. And that's what I was really thinking when I wrote my previous comment.